# Has there ever been a member of the X-Men who wasn't a mutant?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

In the Marvel Universe there are humans, mutates (humans bestowed with powers), gods, aliens, [Homo Superior Superiors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutant_%28Marvel_Comics%29#.22Homo_Superior_Superior.22) (evolution's solution to the mutant problem), and mutants.

Are the X-Men an exclusionary group that will only take members who share the same genetic aberration as they do?

Comment: Was Lockheed an x-man?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Several<sup>1</sup>:

### Members who have never been Mutants

**Madelyne Pryor** - Possessed no powers, served as technical support.

> Associated with the X-men as she is a clone of Jean Grey

**Longshot** - A manufactured humanoid action celebrity from Mojoworld.

**Fantomex** - Escaped sentinal experiment from the Weapon Plus Program

**Mimic** - Dad's potion allowed him to mimic mutants powers.

**Hepzibah** - Extraterrestrial

**Lockheed** - Alien Dragon from Kitty Pryde's fairy-tale bedtime story. 'Nuff said.

**Juggernaut** - Ex-champion of Cyttorak

**Omega Sentinel** - Cyborg sentinel

**Bamfs** - *[Not Actually Bamfs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14274/3804)*. Non-mutants from an alternate dimension.

**Sharon Friedlander** - Enhanced by a Demon Bear. Acted as a nurse, joined Moira’s X-men.

**Tom Corsi** - Another Demon Bear victim/member of Moiras X-men.

**Charlotte Jones** - Detective member, given a suit by Forge. Warren's Girlfriend for a while.

**Moira MacTaggert** - Maid, Xavier's lover, M16 user, genius.

### Members who did not see field work

**Stevie Hunter** - Kitty Pryde's dance teacher and physiotherapist to the team.

### Members that temporarily lost their mutanthood

**Storm** - Went 41 issues in the mid-'80s without powers, even leading the team!

### Members that permanently lost their mutanthood

**Polaris** - Lost her powers and [X-genes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14606/3804) on [M-Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris_%28comics%29#Decimation), regained facsimile powers via [spinal implant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris_%28comics%29#Horseman_of_Apocalypse)

**Magneto** - Lost his powers and [X-genes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14606/3804) on [M-Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto_%28comics%29#House_of_M), regained facsimile powers via [special armour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto_%28comics%29#Manifest_Destiny).

<sub>1. Names taken from [here](https://www.toplessrobot.com/2011/06/11_x-men_who_arent_actually_mutants.php?page=2), and [here](http://www.sidekickcomicsuk.com/blogs/blog4.php/2011/07/13/ten-of-the-best-non-mutant-x-men-charact) other details from wiki/memory.</sub>

Comment: Now I'm confused. Is there a reason you listed Magneto and Storm as examples of non-mutants?

Comment: @JackBNimble Yes indeed.

Comment: I was going to cite that Topless Robot article I wrote, but @Pureferret did it for me! Awesome!

Comment: Wow, I didn't even *see* your name. Good list! (and you know it's accurate if @BrettWhite wrote it!)

Comment: @Pureferret: Even if they lost their powers they still possess the mutant X-gene. I would say they are still technically mutants.

Comment: @JackBNimble See my latest edit.

Comment: Did I just get an unupvote? How can I improve the question?

Comment: It's possible that Namor the Sub-Mariner belongs on this list; I don't read X-Men comics at this time, but I couldn't help but notice he's been an integral part of the franchise in recent years.

Comment: Namor is a mutant. It's been established that not only is he a human/Atlantean hybrid, his human side carries the X-Gene.

Comment: To be fair, it's not correct to say that Madelyne Pryor was associated with the team BECAUSE she's a clone of Jean Grey. She originally started dating Scott (or vice-versa), THEN began supporting the team. It wasn't until later that everyone learned she was a clone, at which time she left the team, snapped, and became the villainous Goblyn Queen.

Comment: Are you sure Madelyne Pryor possessed no powers? I'm pretty sure she has *all* of Jean Grey's powers.

Comment: @mikeenfield I'm confident for a long time she didn't.

Comment: Wasn't Deadpool a in X-Men once? He's not technically a mutant

Comment: @Gallifreyan says who?

Comment: It's been stated in some media (the game, the film, some comics) that he is a _mutate_, i.e. someone who was not born as a mutant but mutated after. At least that's what Wikipedia says, and this was my general impression.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I can't find anything one way of the other. I always thought it was a latent mutant power, nothing that happened to him *gave* him those powers (cf. spiderman's radioactive spider bite) but just *activated them*. Worth a new question.

Comment: @Omegacron - While this is true, it's hard to argue that the reason she and Scott got involved has nothing to do with the fact that she turned out to be a clone of Jean Grey.

Answer (score 2):

Longshot is not a mutant; he is an artificially created humanoid life-form, with the ability to defy probability. (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longshot#Origins)

He was an X-Man in the 1980s during the Outback era.

Answer (score 0):

Ink. Joined in Young X-Men, his mutant tattoo artist imbued him with super-powers through symbolic tattoos. He didn't find out he wasn't a mutant until a few issues into the series.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of additions:

- **Cloak and Dagger** - both the result of a drug experiment
- **Danger** - the Danger Room turned sentient, Shi'ar technology
- **Deathlok** - cyborg

Comment: Did Cloak and Dagger actually join the X-Men at any time, though? Unless you're counting Norman Osborn's Dark X-Men...

Comment: Danger was never actually an X-Man, just a recurring villain.