# Why didn't Spider-Man become a member of the X-Men?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, spider-man

Why didn't Spider-Man join the roster of the X-Men? (Until I asked this question, I had always thought he was a mutant.)

Comment: In the '94 animated series, Spider-Man visited the X-Mansion. He was seeking a cure, however, rather than joining the team. There seems to also be a comic series with the same title (Mutant Agenda), but I haven't read and don't know how similar the plot is. https://spiderman-animated.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mutant_Agenda

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Although the X-Men have occasionally taken on non-mutant members, Spider-man hasn't shown interest in joining. Until recently, Spider-man had always been an independent adventurer and did not join up with other super-heroes in teams.

In the current continuity he is both a member of the Avengers and the [FF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Foundation). This is a new role for Peter Parker, who has matured since his youthful independent days. So it's possible, I suppose, that he could someday join an X-Men franchise - but since he's booked up with Avengers and FF that currently seems unlikely.

Comment: I'm going to answer this specifically, but place it as a longer answer.

Answer (score 26):

I hesitate to answer in case this is too obvious but... because he is not a mutant.  He has superpowers from a coincidental encounter, he doesn't have the mutant gene specific to those who become X-Men.

Comment: [Not all X-Men were mutants](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14284/has-there-ever-been-a-member-of-the-x-men-who-wasnt-a-mutant)

Comment: They were the exceptions.  I assume the OP is approaching this from Spiderman's mutant-like nature, otherwise the same question can be posed about any Marvel superhero.

Comment: Hmmmm...I had always assumed that, because Spiderman had mutated, he was a mutant.

Comment: @MajorStackings Spider-man and others like him are called [mutates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutate_(comics))

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Spider-Man has a **history** of teaming up with other heroes. Though not officially canon, the "Spider Friends" have had several adventures together, and his friendship with both Ice Man *and* Fire Star was shown to be deep even beyond their college years. (Angelica even helped him while she was a New Warrior in the 1993 *Maximum Carnage* arc.) He's worked with the Secret Defenders, served the Fantastic Four and S.H.E.I.L.D. in various capacities (most notably in the *Ultimate Spider-Man* world) and has been a "Reserve Avenger" since  **at least** the 1990s.

I can't remember the story, but there was a cross-over in the Spider books where he, Punisher, Moon Knight, Night Thrasher  and somebody else (Dark Hawk, I think) had to team up to rescue Nova (Thrasher's fellow *New Warrior* at the time) from this massive crime organization which had made some super-human cyborg operatives and sought to take it to a next step by augmenting super-humans. In that book, both he *and* Moon Knight were shown to be "reserve Avengers" in possession of a telecommunication card, which was issued to all Avengers members.

As to *why* he never "joined" the X-Men, well... Spider-Man, much like Hulk, Sasquatch, Scorpion, the Lizard,  Spider-Woman (both versions) and some other Marvel non-mutant characters are what's known as "human mutates." Unlike the X-Men, who were all *born* with an X-gene which had them develop their abilities *naturally,* Mutates are humans who via some kind of accident develop their abilities from an *outside* source. It can be chemical, technical, energy-based, or whatever, but while it *does* alter their genetic structure (or in rare cases, activate a dormant x-gene) they weren't *born* with active genes, which is the *hallmark* of a mutant.

On a bigger scale, due to his non-mutant status, it could be argued that Peter wouldn't be able to "identify" with the mutant condition the same way, and he may have had a moral issue about that. It's the difference between *dating* someone of a different race and thus suffering *some* effects of racism, versus *being* a person of a different race and receiving the negative aspects of it full bore.

Lastly, a good portion of the X-Men joined as adolescents or young adults; Peter had already been a practicing super-hero for **years** before their para-military vigilante organization went public. Though he *does* work well with teams, Pete's sense of commitment is another thing; he has always been about defending New York, being the "Friendly neighborhood Spider-Man," and the X-Men often times face greater world threats. I don't think he'd easily give up doing that anymore than Daredevil would look to expand his reach permanently beyond Hell's Kitchen, especially considering his responsibilities to both Mary Jane, the *Bugle* and Aunt May.

Comment: The Moon Knight crossover that you're thinking of was Round Robin: The Sidekick's Revenge https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Round_Robin:_The_Sidekick%27s_Revenge!

Comment: @Raj ahhh, i see. That _does_ sound familiar. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Spider-man initially was not thought of as Mutant because it was radioactivity from the spider bite that was thought to have caused him to change into the Spider-man we know. He really did actually mutate but Professor X did not want to go down another path of mutations unless they were actually born with the X-Gene. So Peter was never really born with this gene so technically not a mutant.

Comment: What does Professor X have to do with this?